# Accepting a Language Vs Rejecting a language

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I have a question on complexity theory.  I have the following definition in my notes:

> If algorithm A is such that A(s) halts with output 1 for all s in language L, then A accepts L.

My question is, can we still say that A accepts L if A(s) halt with output 1 and s is not in L?  That is, does an algorithm that just returns 1 accept every language?

Thanks

Comment: NOTE: I have seen another similar definition for acceptance of a language:  Given an algorithm A, we say that A accepts a string x if A(x)=1.  The language accepted by an algorithm A is:  {x: A(x)=1}.  With this definition, we would have that if A just returns 1, then the language accepted by A is the language comprised of every possible string of symbols.  Therefore, if L is a strict subset of the set of all possible strings of symbols, we cannot say that A accepts L.  Is this right?

Comment: Therefore, if A accepts language L, then x is in L if and only if A(x)=1.  That is, x is in L implies A(x)=1, and A(x)=1 implies x is in L.  This is not the same as A decides L.  Indeed, suppose A(x)=1 iff x is in L, but if x is not in L, A goes into an infinite loop.  Then A does not reject the compliment of L and so does not decide L.  This shows that the ONLY way for A to accept L but NOT reject the compliment of L, is for A to go into an infinite loop on input x not in L